# multi-product project layout with svn and maven

Tags: svn, maven-2, build-process, build-automation

I need to migrate a project from Ant to Maven.
This project has multiple proprietary packages (lets say, stacked in 3/4 layers. some of the layers share the same svn repo).
Also, it's using ~30 3rd party packages (which are currently manages with svn:externals).
On top of that, there are ~10 different "products" (different packagings of the packages above + some i18n + some .properties + launch4j and such).

What would be the classic layout of such an environment wrt. Maven modules and svn reops?
We plan to branch frequently across packages.

thanks, asaf :-)

---

A simplified outline of the project (and each of it's branches, if changes are required in several packages and products):

```
+ 3rd party
  + log4j
    - log4j.jar
  + junit
    - junit.jar
  ...

+ that-package
  + src
  + bin
  + lib
    - log4j.jar

+ this-package
  + src
  + bin
  + lib
    - that-package.jar

+ product A
  + resources
  + launcher
  + lib
    - this-package.jar
    - that-package.jar

+ product B
  + resources
  + launcher
  + lib
    - this-package.jar
    - that-package.jar
    - 3rd-party.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're asking for but have a look at:

- [How to Migrate from Ant to Maven: Project Structure](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/08/how-to-migrate-from-ant-to-maven-project-structure/)

Also check this previous answer:

- [Maven parent pom vs modules pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992213/maven-parent-pom-vs-modules-pom)

Comment: 10x for answering my vague question. I've learned from your other posts here at SO.

Comment: @Asaf Well, I did not much but you're welcome. And glad you liked some other answers.