# Why Maven asks me for distribution config in every module in multi-module site deployment?

Tags: maven-2, maven

My multi-module Maven project looks like:

```
/foo
  pom.xml
  /foo-parent
  /foo-core
  /foo-something
  /src
    /site
```

Pay attention that `foo` is not a parent project, but `foo-parent` is (for `foo-core` and `foo-something`). `foo` is not inheriting from `foo-parent`. Site configuration is stored in `foo`. All other sub-modules don't know anything about project site and don't have `<distributionManagement>`. mvn site works perfect,  and now I'm running `mvn site-deploy`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0.1:deploy
(default-deploy) on project foo-parent: Missing site information in the 
distribution management element in the project.. -> [Help 1]
```

Maven is trying to `site-deploy` every sub-module individually?? Is it a correct behavior?

Comment: What is your sub-projects inheritance model/layout?

Comment: @JohnS I updated the question. `foo-parent` is parent of `foo-core` and `foo-something`.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441685/multi-module-maven-project-with-parent-pom-and-svn-layout/4442077#4442077 Does it help you?

Comment: I can't understand why you have your site in a parent directory?

Comment: @JohnS Where should I place my site? It is now in "foo" module. Which module should I place it into?

Comment: Create a foo-site directory beside your other foo-xxx directories and put src/site and its pom.xml there so that other modules does not consider it as parent module and do not inherit its site plugin declaration.

Comment: @JohnS: There's nothing wrong with having a top level site.xml file for the project, even if he has a module that is the 'parent' project.  The site.xml is there so that when the site documentation when generated is navigable between modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to your distribution config question:

Maven won't let a child module be the parent pom of the top level pom.xml. That's Maven's way of telling you that you not structuring you project to convention.

You'll have to make foo's pom.xml a parent pom for all modules in the whole project.

The workaround for what you are trying to structure, have the modules that depend on foo-parent, list foo-parent's pom.xml in the parent section of their pom.  Then have foo-parent list foo's pom.xml in its parent section.  You can get away with having foo-parent be the parent pom.xml for all the other modules because all modules are peers to each other in structure layout.

The top level pom.xml should only contain the necessary information to be shared between all modules.

In regards to your site-deploy question:

Maven tries to deploy every site individually for each module because of the top level /src/site/site.xml you have setup.  But this is also partly due to the fact that your probably running site-deploy from the top level (foo).  If you only want the documentation for foo-parent, run site-deploy only on foo-parent.  However, you may not get any of the documentation for the other modules linked into foo-parent's site documentation.

P.S.  Better read up on Maven 3.  There are some very significant changes to the site documentation generation coming!

**EDIT:** Links for reference:

- [Maven 3 Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-SiteandReporting)
- [Maven 3 Site Plugin Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-and-site-plugin.html)

Comment: Can you give a link on where to read about site creation in Maven 3? I still can't understand what is the **correct** way of creating/deploying site(s) in multi-module project...

Comment: @Vincenzo: Added the links to the answer.

Comment: Links are now [Maven 3 Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes?src=search) and [Maven 3 Site Plugin Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+and+site+plugin?src=search)