# Commit multi-module maven project to SVN

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

I used Maven to create several projects in Eclipse, based on Maven archetypes, and ended up with this project structure (a parent project with multiple modules):

- Parent project - pom.xml:

```xml
<name>backoffice-root</name>    
<modules>
    <module>backoffice-web</module>
    <module>backoffice-ejb-core</module>
    <module>backoffice-ws</module>
    <module>backoffice-ear</module>
</modules>
```

Now I want to commit them to a SVN repository using Subclipse.

In my first approach, I added these projects to SVN in a flat hierarchy. The first project that I added was root, otherwise I'd get a warning saying that .svn folders in modules would be deleted:

```
backoffice-root    
backoffice-web
backoffice-ejb-core
backoffice-ws
backoffice-ear
```

If I try to commit after that I get an error "backoffice-root/backoffice-web is already under version control". I believe this happens because when I added the projects to SVN, a .svn folder was created inside each one of them, but I don't know how can I solve this problem without deleting these folders and losing the information contained within them.

So I tried a second approach: adding root to SVN and then all the others under root (mapping my Maven project structure to SVN repository), creating this structure in the repository:

```
backoffice-root    
    backoffice-web
    backoffice-ejb-core
    backoffice-ws
    backoffice-ear
```

But when I try to commit all of them, I get the same error of approach #1.

The only way that I get things to work is by just adding root to SVN and committing it (it commits all the modules since they are folders inside root). But I want to work on each project and commit them individually. Do I need to structure my Maven projects in a flat layout like explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441685/multi-module-maven-project-with-parent-pom-and-svn-layout) post? How does one work this way with my original layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working with the same your layout and everythings work. My project's skeleton is the following:

```
parent
  -model
  -util
  -services
  -web
```

model,util,services and web are all modules to parent and are placed in parent directory. Then I committed the parent project (that contains all modules) and finally I checked out and importing (In eclipse File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven Project) all modules.

**Update1**

Try to describe the procedure along some screenshoot:

Step1 I already committed the parent and all modules

[image]

After checkout you will wind the following situation:

[image]

where only the parent is linked with the svn. Now you have to do (File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven Project and selected all modules. Then automatically you will have all modules linked at the svn

[image]

**Update2**

My parent definition is the following:

```
<modules>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>util</module>
    <module>services</module>
    <module>vaadin-webapp</module>
</modules>
```

and each module has instead this configuration

```
<parent>
    <groupId>myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: I already have the maven projects in my workspace (I created each one of them), so I cannot import them like you said. How do you commit a single project? Do you select its folder under parent project and commit it?

Comment: Doesn't that modify your parent and modules pom files so that they refer to each other like in a flat layout?

Comment: @Bederous I don't understand what you said but in the way describe above I'm able to manage (commit,revert ecc) each module in an indipendent way to the other ones

Comment: I was asking if your parent project pom.xml file has the modules defined like this:

 <modules>
  <module>../service</module>
  <module>../models</module>
 </modules> And the modules refer to parent project like this: <parent><relativePath>../parent</relativePath></parent>

Comment: I deleted the modules projects from Eclipse (without deleting them from the disk), since it was the only way Eclipse would let me import thereafter. I then did the Import you suggested and it seems to be working. Nevertheless, I find this procedure is quite unnatural. I wonder if the flat layout approach is the correct one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61993/discussion-between-skizzo-and-baderous).