# how to run only parent pom.xml in maven multi-module project

Tags: module, maven, profile

I have maven multi-modules project. At the parent level, i have some java files. And in the parent pom.xml, at the package phase i do some stuff.

Usually, when i run mvn package at parent level, the package phase of parent pom will be run and all the modules will be packaged as well.

I am looking for a way that allow me to do these (when i run mvn package):

- allow me to run only paren pom.xml (the script at the package phase), not the modules. This is the 1st priority.
- allow me to run paren pom.xml  and some particular modules (like module 1, module 2 BUT not module 3 , module 4).

Can i use profile for those issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

While I agree with the fact that you may not have optimal project structure, the answer is that Maven 2.2.1 has an option "--non-recursive" which satisfies your first requirement:

```
-N,--non-recursive    Do not recurse into sub-projects
```

So something like this:

```
mvn --non-recursive clean compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to have java code on the top level? In my opinion this is not a very good idea. Have your code in the subprojects and let the top-level project be responsible for holding the general information and configuration of the entire project.

If you have some base-library code in the top-level project now, you can put it in a sub-project and set up dependencies between the projects.

Comment: I have several multi-module projects where site documentation is in /src/site/markdown in the root of the project (same level as parent pom).  Being able to run 'mvn site -N' means I can iterate on my rendered documentation without having to build every sub-module.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Maven parent pom vs modules pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992213/maven-parent-pom-vs-modules-pom)

The nature of your question indicates that your project structure may not be optimal.