# How to run maven plugin for only root of multimodule project

Tags: maven

I'm using `mvn com.package:plugin:goal` command, but it runs first for the root, and then for every module.
But I want to run it only for the root.

I found `-pl=module` parameter, but how to pass `root` there?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811870/how-to-run-only-parent-pom-xml-in-maven-multi-module-project, there is a non-recursive option.

Comment: Thanks, @Tunaki, thaths the case!