# How can a root have a parent?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, root, parent

Trying to solve some my problems and looking at many wise discussions such as:

[Maven parent pom vs modules pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992213/maven-parent-pom-vs-modules-pom),

I came to a conclusion that I do not understand something absolutely basic in all that stuff about POMs.

### How can a POM that is a root one, have a parent or even maybe parents?

It seems that maven has special interpretation of what is the parent and what is the root. But I am afraid that all documentation that I have found takes such simple terms for something already known. Sorry, they are not such for me.

Comment: The root mechanism and the parent mechanism are not overlapping.  You can have both in the same pom.xml.

Comment: Parent is a reference to another pom. OK. What is 'root' them?

Comment: A Pom with modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as to explain a bit about How root POM have Parent I need to take help of example.

Whenever we initialize any project using Spring Boot then we use following parent definition in pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Now this parent definition facilitate inheritance of common managed dependencies needed to for your application to behave in Spring boot way. These parents have their own pom.xml and those pom mentions common dependencies. Maven central repositories understands these Poms.  **So this is kind of pom to pom inheritance.**

Few of examples of inherited managed dependencies are:
**1. Logging using slf4j
2. testing using junit**

and so on... and so many..

So here opinionated Spring Boot Project becomes parent project and your maven root pom.xml become beneficiary.

Comment: Yes, that example looks like that mess I have in my project... And how the maven knows where to look for that parent? For we don't have any URL or file here.

Comment: So, that "parent" is practically something as a used library/repository? What is the difference between "parent" and "dependency" then?

Comment: @Gangnus - These parents have their own pom.xml and those pom mentions common dependencies. Maven central repositories understands these Poms.

Comment: So this is kind of pom to pom inheritance.

Comment: But then in what sense the root POM is root? I thought that means that others POMs depend on it and it does not depend on anything.

Comment: Its root from application or domain perspective

Comment: Could you add that additional info from comments into the answer - I will gladly check it as the answer then.

Comment: Yeah I have added that in answer