# Pass properties to maven sub-module, which does not have current module as parent

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have several maven-projects:

- commons-lib (*simple Java project*)
- user-service (*Spring-Boot-driven project*)
- composite-service (*Spring-Boot-driven project*)
- frontend-service (*Spring-Boot- / Angular2-driven project*)
- all-services-parent (*parent project building everything else*)

While **commons-lib** is unlikely to ever be released separately, all other projects (except for the parent) might be released separately.

If the first four in the list are sub-modules of the fifth, do they **have to** have their parent set to parent (e.g. all-services-parent) in return?

Since I want to include *commons-lib* in the user- and composite-services I understand that I have to have it built first. However: each of the services above may be released separately - so which building structure is most proper for what I need?

Would it be:

```
-- all-services-parent
   |-- (maven sub-module) commons-lib
   |-- (maven sub-module) user-service
   |-- (maven sub-module) composite-service
   |-- (maven sub-module) frontend-service
```

or:

```
-- all-services-parent
   |-- user-service-parent
       |-- (maven sub-module) commons-lib
       |-- (maven sub-module) user-service
   |-- composite-service-parent
       |-- (maven sub-module) commons-lib
       |-- (maven sub-module) composite-service
   |-- frontend-service
```

The second building structure would allow me to build all the JARs by calling "mvn clean install" on all-services-parent while still being able to build separate projects properly by calling "mvn clean install" on the corresponding parent, but is it really how it's done?

In my current setup I am trying to use the first building structure, but since e.g. composite-service has "spring-boot-starter-parent" set as its parent, I cannot access the properties or anything from the "all-services-parent"-module.

I read into [Maven parent pom vs modules pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992213/maven-parent-pom-vs-modules-pom) (a question that looked promising at first), but it did not apply to my case as much as I would like it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to import the spring boot parent and not inherit from it like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
       </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: But what would I do thereafter? Should I be always setting the module-parent as the parent in a sub-module's pom.xml?

Comment: It seems this suggestion is the closest to solving my problem. I decided to go with the first build-structure and using profiles, that are active by default, but also allow to build individual module groups. I still have no idea how to pass properties to child-modules, but I circumvented that need. Also it seems to not be a good idea to use variables in e.g. the version- or group-tag in a pom.xml, because that would unnecessarily tie modules together.

Answer (score 0):

Parent module properties file can access by sub modules but sub modules properties file cannot access to other sub modules. 
 **or** 
 
You need to do separate properties file for each sub modules.

Comment: That I know (sub-modules cannot access the properties of other sub-modules). In my case I am just not sure whether I should be trying to set up the first building structure or the second one (see the pre-tags in my post).

Answer (score -1):

Add your sub modules like this in your pom.xml file and give its absolute path.

This should be work

```
<modules>
        <module>../TestWeb</module>
        <module>../TestBusiness</module>
        <module>../MsgScheduler</module>
        <module>../Connector</module>                   
</modules>
```

Comment: That I have already done - I did read the manual. It's just that I was not able to inherit properties, because I thought I could not adjust the parent to anything else than the spring-boot-starter-parent, but apparently I can (see Sandor Juhos' reply).